# splice array returns empty reults

Tags: javascript, array-splice

I am trying to use splice top remove the last 2 items from an array. It always returns nothing. Trying to figure out what i am missing

```js
function planets_remove() {
  var planetsArray = [];
  planetsArray.push(document.getElementById("planets").value);
  var martian = planetsArray.splice(4,2)[0];
  document.getElementById("planets_removed").innerHTML = martain;
}
```

```html
Enter 7 Planets<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="planets" name"planets"></textarea>
<br><br>
Click to remove the last 2 items from the array<br>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="planets_remove()">Remove</button><br>
<p id="planets_removed"><p>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="planets_remove()">Remove</button><br>
```

Comment: sorry about that, for some reason it did not copy/paste correctly, i updated it.

Comment: OK, you declare an empty array as a local valuable, you add one item to it, then immediately try to remove two items?

Comment: You create an empty array and then push only 1 item on it, why would you expect splicing 2 items starting at index 4 get you anything when you only have 1 item? Did you mean to split the data entered in the textarea into your planetsArray?

Comment: Im not pushing 1 item, i am pushing multiple from the text box. I am writing in 7 planets. pluto, sun. earth, jupiter, mars, venus, mercury, converting that into an array. then I splice the last 2 planets,  Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: You are not pushing multiple, [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will only push 1 item at a time into an array

Comment: ok, so then how to i push multiple items to an array? I'm obviously a noob...lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this Javascript code:

```
function planets_remove() {
  var planetsArray = document.getElementById("planets").value.split('\n');
  var martian = planetsArray.splice(0, planetsArray.length - 2);
  document.getElementById("planets_removed").innerHTML = martian;
}
```

The problem was, you were not pushing 7 elements, you were just pushing one multi-line string to an array.

You have to split the the string, so that it converts to individual elements. And then you can splice it.

Answer (score 0):

Your array only ever contains one element (at most).

Solution: add a button to add new planet to the array after every input

```
Enter 7 Planets<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="planets" name"planets"></textarea><br><br>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="planets_add()"> Add </button><br>

Click to remove the last 2 items from the array<br>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="planets_remove()"> Remove </button><br>
<p id="planets_removed"><p>

var planetsArray = [];
function planets_add() {
  planetsArray.push(document.getElementById("planets").value);
}

function planets_remove() {
  var martian = planetsArray.splice(4,2)[0];
  document.getElementById("planets_removed").innerHTML = martain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split `textarea` value by some splitter, here is example with space(' ').

```js
function planets_remove() {
  var planetsTxt = document.getElementById("planets");
  var planetsArray = planetsTxt.value.split(' ');
  var martian = planetsArray.splice(planetsArray.length - 2, 2);
  document.getElementById("planets_removed").innerHTML = martian.join(' ');
planetsTxt.value = planetsArray.join(' ');
}
```

```html
Enter 7 Planets<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="planets" name"planets"></textarea>
<br><br>
Click to remove the last 2 items from the array<br>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="planets_remove()">Remove</button><br>
<p id="planets_removed"><p>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="planets_remove()">Remove</button><br>
```